# Where can I find 'winmm.lib' (I'm using Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx, winmm

My OS is 64Bit Windows 7.
I wanted to build the DirectX Sample in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Samples\C++\Direct3D10\Tutorials\Tutorial02.
but when I build error occured with fatal error

> LNK1104: 'winmm.lib' can't open the file.

I reinstalled Direct SDK, but no change. I also added the path (include, lib) to the settings.

If I remove 'winmm.lib' from the project settings, 'comctl32.lib' can't be opened.
both libs were already present in properties>Linker>Input.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where did you add the pathes? Did you check that winmm.lib is present on your hard drive?

Comment: It should be in `C:/winows/system32` add this path to your library pathes

Comment: Those (both) are Windows SDK libraries: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib or around.

Comment: It will certainly not be in `C:/winows/system32` I do not have a single .lib file at all in this folder. Maybe you are thinking about .dlls.

Comment: `LNK1104: 'winmm.lib' can't open the file.` Are you mixing x86_64 and x86? Remember you can not use 64 bit libraries in 32 bit applications or 32 bit libraries in 64 bit applications.

Comment: @RomanR. right, the sdk should do the trick..., switched to linux for a long time ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Just put the line below in stdafx.h

```
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
```

Comment: I was getting "LNK2028 unresolved token (0A00002D) extern C ..." messages when starting a project that used functions from winmm.dll. Adding the "#pragma comment ..." to add the reference to winmm.lib as above fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`winmm.lib` isn't part of the DirectX SDK but is part of the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138).

Latest Windows SDK versions were also heavily reorganized but it includes the library you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build any of the legacy DirectX SDK samples with VS 2012 or VS 2013, you need to modify the include/libs paths per the instructions on bottom of the page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). The most important change is that you must reverse the Include/Lib path order:

For VS 2010 it was:

`$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)`

`$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86;$(LibraryPath)` or `$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64;$(LibraryPath)`

For VS 2012/2013 it has to be:

`$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include`

`$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86` or `$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64`

Of course a better option is not spend time learning the older Direct3D 10 API at all, and use the latest [Direct3D 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/07/11/getting-started-with-direct3d-11.aspx) Win32 desktop tutorials on [MSDN Code Gallery](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef). In fact, I've posted many of the legacy DirectX SDK samples there so they work fine with VS 2012/2013 Express for Windows Desktop and VS 2012/2013 Pro+ as-is without the DirectX SDK at all.

Read these blog posts:

[DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx)

[DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog.aspx)

[Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)

[DirectX SDKs of a certain age](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx)

And review these CodePlex projects:

[DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929)

[DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981)

[DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926)

[DXUT for Direct3D 11](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320437)

[Effects 11](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568)